# smartgwt beginner- error when trying to compile project using Smart GWT

Tags: smartgwt, gwt2

I have followed the instructions at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/advanced-smartgwt-tutorial-part-1.html and tried to create a simple screen that uses Smart GWT.

I have also combined this with a popup window that is basically to allow the user to sign in via Oauth- it is invoked with a single line of code from the main window of browser.

When I try to build this project in Eclipse, I am getting the following errors---

UPDATE--

```
 Internal validation error               java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
ISC_DataBinding.js  /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/modules  line 0  JavaScript Problem
```

Given below is a list of errors that were occurring previously, these got eliminated by going to Project Preferences->Validation-> Disabling XML validation. (These were part of the original question- I have updated this question now that I have resolved the problems due to the below errors myself...)

```
Description     Resource    Path    Location    Type

Content is not allowed in prolog.       DBListDS.ds.xml /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       DBSchema.ds.xml /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       DataSource.ds.xml   /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       DataSourceField.ds.xml  /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       DataSourceStore.ds.xml  /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       JVMClassTreeDS.ds.xml   /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       QuartzJobs.ds.xml   /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       QuartzScheduler.ds.xml  /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       QuartzTriggers.ds.xml   /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       SchemaSet.ds.xml    /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.     SimpleType.ds.xml /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       Validator.ds.xml    /Spark     
 Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       WSDLMessage.ds.xml  /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML
Content is not allowed in prolog.       WSOperationHeader.ds.xml    /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       WebService.ds.xml   /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       WebServiceOperation.ds.xml  /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       XSComplexType.ds.xml    /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML 
Content is not allowed in prolog.       XSElement.ds.xml    /Spark Crawler/WebContent/com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.script.OAuth2Script/sc/schema   line 1  XML
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I just changed the processing settings for XML documents from Errors to Warnings in Project->Preferences->Validation. This removed most of the errors that were occurring previously...

Now the only error remaining is gwt error lava.lang.arrayindexoutofbounds exception

How do I determine why and where this error is occurring, so that I can resolve it?

Comment: I suppose you are using the Google GWT Plugin's build and not the Eclipse's project build, correct?

Comment: @gpapaz I am not sure what I am using to build- basically I am letting Eclipse IDE auto-build the code.. I think this is the Eclipse Project build? At this point the error (that I have mentioned above) is occurring...Also, can you tell me how to use Google GWT Plugin's Build?

Comment: Arvid, just look at your toolbar and locate a blue g button. Click its arrow marker and select the GWT Compile Project option. This is needed if you want to test your code from an external HTTP server. To do so, just copy the project's war directory, after you have compiled it to the server's service directory. If you want to use the Jetty embedded in the eclipse debug/run option, right click on the object and select the Run/Debug As -> Web Application option. Then you will provided with a link that you can copy paste in a browser and test your application.

Comment: @gpapaz- thank you, what you have said works perfectly...please put your comment as an answer, and I will select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are compiling the code as a GWT application and not as a pure Java one. To do so you have two options. Either compile your app and use an external web server or run/debug your application through the embedded to Eclipse Jetty web server. For the former, just look at your toolbar and locate a blue g button. Click its arrow marker and select the GWT Compile Project option. Finally, just copy the project's war directory, after the successful compilation to the server's service directory. For the latter, right click on the project and select the Run/Debug As -> Web Application option. Then you will be provided with a link that you can copy paste in a browser and test your application.